# Extracting characters between space and first ":"

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the hour (only) from a variable that has date and time. There are several questions explaining how to extract `%H:%M` from `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M` but my data is structured as `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M` for some observations and as `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S` for others. Furthermore, I don't always have two diigits for hour (one digit hours are in one digit, no leading zero). So using the following, will not work:

```
 df$hour <- format(as.POSIXct(citistation$starttime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), format="%H")
```

Sample of my data:

```
 date <- c("1/1/2013 0:01","12/31/2013 21:49:19")
```

I am leaning towards something that extracts numbers between space and first ":". Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  Match one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) followed by one or more space (`\\s+`), capture the one or more characters that are not a `:` (`([^:]+)`) followed by a `:` and characters until the end of the string, replace it with the the backreference (`\\1`) of the capture group.

```
sub("\\S+\\s+([^:]+):.*", "\\1", date)
#[1] "0"  "21"
```

---

It is better to convert to 'DateTime' class and extract the `hour`

```
library(lubridate)
hour(parse_date_time(date, c('mdy_HM', 'mdy_HMS')))
#[1]  0 21
```

#### data

```
date <- c('1/1/2013 0:01','12/31/2013 21:49:19')
```

Comment: @AgustinIndaco  I was not sure whether it was a single string or two string earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing material in character arguments to as.POSIXct are ignored so you could  shorten your 'format' argument to:

```
format(as.POSIXct(date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), format="%H")
#[1] "00" "21"
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(c("1/1/2013 0:01","12/31/2013 21:49:19"), "\\s+([0-9]+):")[,2]
#[1] "0"  "21"
```